# Php curl System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter

Tags: php, web-services, exception, curl

I'm trying to reach a web service (works fine on local) via Internet Explorer with CURL, but I got this error message:

System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: server. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Here is my call:

```
    $aParamWS["serverName"] = $paramArray["serverName"];
$aParamWS["userName"] = $paramArray["userName"];

$sUrl_ws = "http://myServer/WS_TEST/test_webService.asmx/TestMethod";
    $curl = curl_init($sUrl_ws);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PhpRestClient");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
foreach($aParamWS as $key=>$value)
{
    $post_array_string .=$key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$post_array_string = rtrim($post_array_string, '&');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($aParamWS));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array_string);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response;
```

I Know this issue have been solve many times, by stringify array, but it still does not work.
Any idea ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$aParamWS["serverName"] = $paramArray["serverName"];
```

I notice you have "serverName" in your parameters but not "server".  Did you mean to "server" as a parameter instead?